# Why is IndexedDB hanging?

Tags: indexeddb, localforage

I'm using IndexedDB through two layers of wrapper, first the [localforage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage) library then the [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) wrapper. For some reason, I sometimes get in situations where attempts to store or get items from the db just completely hang. I've added a timeout to the outer library as a patch so my offline-first app doesn't break, but it seems like there should be some sort of root cause here.

I have set localforage up to only use IndexedDB, so I know it's not some other storage system bugging out.

Clearing storage doesn't fix the issue. I'll check if restarting the browser does, but first I need to post this question to SO

EDIT: restarting the browser fixed this. That also means that it's going to be hard for me to test this until it happens again!

(There might not be enough data here for anyone else to know what's going on, but I like thinking out loud while debugging and hopefully this will be helpful to someone else in the future.)

Comment: In order to get an answer it would help if you provided an example of the code that you think is hanging